# How to add missing domain user to VMWare?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I'm logged into the vSphere Client and I want to add a specific person from our domain to the Global Permissions list.  I set the user prompt to domain and then I search for the name in the search box.  However, this user does not show up.  Our other users do show up though (even a couple calendar objects show up!).  This user has been with us for over a year, so I don't know why he wouldn't have replicated by now.  Is there some way to *force* a username in even when it doesn't find it naturally?  Or, is there a way to make it update the list?

Comment: Is he in a different branch of the domain?  If you search AD for his account do you find it in an unusual place?  Do you have the correct username?  (Sorry, most common cause of this problem though.)  Also, common practice in Windows is to populate the local group with a domain group and put the users in the domain group.  So if you put the group in the Global Permissions list and add him to the group?  I know none of these are answers but maybe one of these suggestions will shake something loose.

Comment: Same group as other users that do appear.  Search even uses the first/last name fields and I can pick up others with the same first name.  Starting the last name gets others that match, but misses this one.  I may have another group that I could safely add without pulling in other people.  I'll see about dropping him in there to see what happens.

Comment: Ugh, that one group that I could safely do *also* isn't seen by VMWare.  It seems very hit or miss what it does see.  Very frustrating that I can assign admin access easily to guys running machines on the shop floor, but I can't give admin to an IT tech!

Comment: Check the permissions on the shop floor users' accounts and the admin accounts.  Perhaps a VMWare service account has permissions on the shop guys that aren't on the admin accounts?  Or compare working admin accounts with both groups?

Comment: I've got AD open on my screen too and it's correct there.  whoami also comes back correct.

Comment: If there's something in permissions I'm not seeing it.  I've been going down a company directory and found more missing, but it seems so very random who shows and who doesn't.  Length of service doesn't seem to matter.  Access levels/group memberships don't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the HTML5 UI, try it using the flash UI. I have a lot of users and groups that show up in the flash UI and not in the HTML5 UI.

I actually started the habit of giving permissions with the PowerCLI, it's much faster than via the UI.

Comment: Correct.  A great many more accounts show up in Flash than in HTML.  I've been defaulting to using HTML, I guess I'll just have to stick with Flash despite the pain of Flash.  I like PowerCLI, but I make changes so infrequently that I can never remember the syntax...